# EF6 SqlQuery with named parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure accepting a few paramaters but I can't figure out the right syntax. According to varios sources, the following should work:

```
var results = base.Context.Database.SqlQuery<UserSummary>("exec FindPatients forenames = @forenames, surname = @surname",
new SqlParameter("@forenames", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(forenames) ? (object)DBNull.Value : forenames),
new SqlParameter("@surname", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(surname) ? (object)DBNull.Value : surname));
```

When .ToList() is called, I get an SqlException: `Incorrect syntax near '='.`

I've tried removing the exec:

```
var results = base.Context.Database.SqlQuery<UserSummary>("FindPatients @forenames, @surname",
new SqlParameter("@forenames", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(forenames) ? (object)DBNull.Value : forenames),
new SqlParameter("@surname", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(surname) ? (object)DBNull.Value : surname));
```

Which results in `The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection`

I don't want to use numbered parameters and pass {1}, {2} etc in to the sproc as I need 10 or so parameters and it's a maintenance nightmare. Am I missing something?

Comment: @er-shoaib "Incorrect syntax near '='". I don't want to use numbered paramaters because remembering the order is difficult to remember for me and other devs, and requires an extra step to check the Db for the correct order.

Comment: @er-shoaib yep, "Incorrect syntax near '='"

Comment: When I use the profiled to track the SQL executed, it's calling sp_execute SQL, but that command works when I copy/paste and run it via SSMS.

Comment: second one works for me

Comment: Why you deleted your own answer? Named parameters definitely require `@` before the parameter name.